# Not receiving output from ProcessBuilder in YARN job

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, fedora-25

I have a Hadoop YARN cluster set up on some machines at my university (all machines running Linux Fedora 25). When running a mapreduce job in YARN, I am unable to receive the output from a call I make to a separate program. Interestingly, if I run my job locally (configured in mapred-site.xml), my method for calling the program and receiving its output works just fine. Below is my executeShellCommand class, which is instantiated and used in my first map task.

```
public class ExecuteShellCommand {


    public String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            String [] args = command.split(" ");
            String cmd = args[0];
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd, args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7]).directory(new File("path to executable"));
            p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            p.waitFor();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
            }
    return output.toString();

    }

}
```

Things I have made sure to check:

1) Permissions are appropriately set for all files/directories needed

2) Map tasks are run as current user (me), so no issues with illegal access

3) I am not receiving a file not found exception, so the path to the program      I'm calling is correct

4) Checked the input/output stream for Process p (input stream set as java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream@1000e80, output stream is null)

5) Instead of calling the program I need to use, I have tried a simple "echo" command, and could not receive that output either.

6) I have also tried using

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myCommand")
```

but the results are the same (no output received)

As I already mentioned, when I run a job locally, my executeCommand method functions perfectly, and returns the output from the program I call. Only in YARN do the issues occur. I have a feeling that the problem caused by either not reading from the correct buffer, or the command issued to ProcessBuilder is never actually executed. I am quite stumped as to how to debug what is going on here, and any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying all sorts of solutions, I figured out how to get the error stream from the process spawned with ProcessBuilder. Turns out when I set the working directory for the process, I forgot to update the path to one of the arguments I was passing it. D'oh!!!